# Nginx + uWSGI worker is killed by signal 6 during a request

Tags: python, uwsgi

nginx + uwsgi + flask

DAMN ! worker 15 (pid: 17149) died, killed by signal 6 :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 15 (new pid: 30157)

what's the meaning of singal 6? And how can I find all the singal meanings?
Which I only knew is that the singal 9 meansit received a SIGKILL, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see meaning of different signals, use `kill -l`

```
> kill -l
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL       5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT      7) SIGEMT       8) SIGFPE       9) SIGKILL     10) SIGBUS
11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGSYS      13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM
16) SIGURG      17) SIGSTOP     18) SIGTSTP     19) SIGCONT     20) SIGCHLD
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGIO       24) SIGXCPU     25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGINFO     30) SIGUSR1
31) SIGUSR2
```

Signal 6, `SIGABRT`, is usually caused by a failed `assert` or by library functions which detect an internal error, or calling `free()` on a non-initialized/corrupted pointer.